# bitwise right shift and 0xFF | Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am trying to understand a piece of code but not able to get clear idea about few points
here is the Java code

```
private String firstMethod(int number){
   return secondMethod(number >> 16 & 0xFF, 0).concat(secondMethod(number >> 8 & 0xFF, 1)).concat(secondMethod(number & 0xFF, 7));
}

private static String secondMethod(int value, int offset)
 {
     return thirdMethod(value >> 4, offset).concat(thirdMethod(value & 0xF, offset + 4));
 }

private static String thirdMethod(int value, int offset)
  {
     String chars = getAlphabet();
     int pos = (value + offset) % 16;
     return chars.substring(pos, pos + 1);
 }
```

value passed to `firstMethod` is a random number for first time and all subsequent call to method will pass value incremented by 1.

I am clear about bit-wise right shift operation as well about the use of `& 0xFF`, however I am still not very clear about following points

- Shifting given value by specific number (like 16 and 8 for first than no sift etc)
- Not clear about use of offset ,specifically passing certain number as offset.

Can anyone help me to understand those 2 point

Comment: the code for third method is cut off

Comment: @Antimony: I added code to third method also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shifting given value by specific number (like 16 and 8 for first than no sift etc)

You are printing bytes as hexi-decimal.  Each byte is 8-bits so you want to shift each byte by

> Not clear about use of offset ,specifically passing certain number as offset.

I am pretty sure the offset is either a) incorrect, b) a really obscure way of masking/encoding the data.

To print a number as a 6 byte hexi-decimal String you can do this.

```
System.out.println(String.format("%06x", 12345));
```

prints

```
003039
```

This is much shorter. ;)

---

`>>` has a surprising low precedence.  This means

```
number >> 16 & 0xFF
```

is actually

```
number >> (16 & 0xFF)
```

or

```
number >> 16
```

what you indedn was

```
(number >> 16) & 0xFF
```

or as the result is unsigned.

```
(number >>> 16) & 0xFF
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying things, however can you please provide some more details regarding your point for offset?

Comment: My point about offset is that if it were not there it would print in hexi - decimal as you might expect. The offset adds a simple cypher which might have been intended but there is no way to know from reading the code.

Answer (score 1):

An integer is a 32-Bit Number.

So as a binary-number, you can represent number as:

XXXXXXXXAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBCCCCCCCC
(X, A, B, C stands for 0 or 1).

number >> 16  gives you XXXXXXXXAAAAAAAA.
number >> 16 & 0xFF gives you AAAAAAAA

By the firstMethod number is splited in 3 Bytes:

AAAAAAAA and BBBBBBBB and CCCCCCC (Shift of 16, shift of 8 and no shift)
and given to the secondMethod.

In the secondMethod the 8 Bits are splited in the higher four bits and the lower four bits.

In the thirdMethod the four Bits is translate to a String containing one char.

But the sense depends on "getAlphabet()".
Perhaps there will be also a usefull interpretation for the offset.

So you have to give further information!